# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [user], expecting one of [min, gender, max]

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I get

```
 INFO 4508 --- [nio-8081-exec-9]  j.r.q.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling : Silently ignoring

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [user], expecting one of [min, gender, max]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.lambda$setParameter$4(QueryParameterSetter.java:113) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling$2.execute(QueryParameterSetter.java:185) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:113) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.lambda$bind$0(ParameterBinder.java:79) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1082) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
```

Code

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
      @Query("select new com.newcode.meeting.domain.dto.UserDto( " +
        " us, " +
        " SUM (case  when ul.userLike = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0  " +
        ") from User us left join us.likes ul  where " +
        " us.birthDate BETWEEN :max and  :min " +
        " and  us.gender =:gender group by us ")
Page<UserDto> findUsersByBirthDateIsBetweenAndGenderDto(
        Pageable pageable,
        @Param("max") LocalDate max,
        @Param("min") LocalDate min,
        @Param("gender") Gender gender,
        @Param("user") User user
);
```

Class UserDto if you need someone to see.
I do not know what else to add so that it does not write -"looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
 import com.newcode.meeting.domain.Image;
 import com.newcode.meeting.domain.ProfileDetail;
 import com.newcode.meeting.domain.User;
 import com.newcode.meeting.domain.Views;
 import com.newcode.meeting.dto.Role;
 import lombok.*;

 import java.net.URL;
 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.time.LocalDateTime;
 import java.util.Set;

 @Data
 @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @ToString(of = {"id", "meLiked"})
 @JsonView(Views.FullProfileDetail.class)
public class UserDto {
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  private URL userpic;
  private Gender gender;
  private LocalDate birthDate;
  private boolean isOnline;
  private Set<Role> roles;
  private boolean active;
  private String region;
  private String country;
  private LocalDateTime lastVisit;
  private ProfileDetail profileDetail;
  @JsonView(Views.FullProfileDetailImage.class)
  private Set<Image> images;
  private boolean meLiked;
  Integer likeNew;

public UserDto(User user, boolean meLiked) {
    this.id = user.getId();
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.userpic = user.getUserpic();
    this.gender = user.getGender();
    this.birthDate = user.getBirthDate();
    this.isOnline = user.isOnline();
    this.roles = user.getRoles();
    this.active = user.isActive();
    this.region = user.getRegion();
    this.country = user.getCountry();
    this.lastVisit = user.getLastVisit();
    this.profileDetail = user.getProfileDetail();
    this.images = user.getImages();
    this.meLiked = meLiked;
    this.likeNew = user.getLikeNew();
}
}

 public UserPageDto getAllUser(User user, String ageMax, String ageMin, String gender, Pageable pageable) {
    user = userRepo.findUserById(user.getId());

    LocalDate minDate = getDateForSearchUser(ageMin);
    LocalDate maxDate = getDateForSearchUser(ageMax);
    Gender sex;

    if (gender.equals(Gender.FEMALE.toString())) {
        sex = Gender.MALE;
    } else {
        sex = Gender.FEMALE;
    }
    Page<UserDto> page = userRepo.findUsersByBirthDateIsBetweenAndGenderDto(pageable, maxDate, minDate, sex, user);
    return new UserPageDto(
            page.getContent(),
            page.getNumber(),
            page.getTotalPages());
}
```

When I added "Pageable" I started getting this error.
But the result is getting the right.
Without "Pageable" or param "user"  works without errors

The question is how to remove this error?

Comment: Which repository interface are you extending?

Comment: Please show "UserDto" and "findUserByBirthDateIsBetweenAndGenderDto()", too.

Comment: So "UserDto" is just a POJO. Q: Which repository interface are you extending? Q: How is "findUserByBirthDateIsBetweenAndGenderDto()" declared?

Comment: Added all......

Comment: extends JpaRepository

Comment: The answers are correct and describe how to work around the problem. There is also a bug report for the underlying issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2140

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.

This error is not referring to your query - it complains about countQuery, which counts all results for pageable, so it can calculate how many pages it got in total.

This countQuery is generated automatically, if not declared explicitly. So it was generated to use all parameters but not User (this generation, as a way to optimize, may ignore ORDER BY or aggregations, because it only needs the count of records matched by query and order or additional data does not matter).

So generated countQuery may look something like this:

```
@Query("select count(us)" +
    "from User us left join us.likes ul  where " +
    " us.birthDate BETWEEN :max and  :min " +
    " and  us.gender =:gender group by us ")
```

As you can see - the amount of affected rows stays the same as in the original query, but :user is not included, which is the reason why Hibernate fails to validate countQuery.

You did not get the same mistake when removing Pageable as a parameter because in that case, countQuery was not generated (and the same when not using the :user param).

You now have three options:

1. Implement your own pagination, using PageImpl.
2. Explicitly define your query to use :user parameter:

```
@Query(value = "select new com.newcode.meeting.domain.dto.UserDto( " +
    " us, " +
    " SUM (case  when ul.userLike = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0  " +
    ") from User us left join us.likes ul  where " +
    " us.birthDate BETWEEN :max and  :min " +
    " and  us.gender =:gender group by us ",
    countQuery = "select count(us)" +
    "from User us left join us.likes ul  where " +
    " us.birthDate BETWEEN :max and  :min " +
    " and  us.gender =:gender group by us " +
    "order by :user)
```

3. First retrieve UserEntities, then when mapping it to DTO - count this additional
   column (by separate JPA query or through the related collection in the Entity using
   Java method).

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the implicit call to countQuery. Try to redefine the query so that all the parameters of the entry are present in it. For instance:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.core.blackfilm.v2.dto.CommentDto(" +
            "c, " +
            "COUNT(cl), " +
            "SUM(case when cl = :author then 1 else 0 end) > 0 " +
            ") " +
            "FROM com c LEFT JOIN c.likes cl " +
            "WHERE c.movie = :movie " +
            "GROUP BY c",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(cl) FROM com c LEFT JOIN c.likes cl WHERE c.movie = :movie AND cl = :author")
    Page<CommentDto> findByMovieId(@Param("movie") Movie movie, @Param("author") User author, Pageable pageable);
```